# unable to get back into macOS from ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, usb, lubuntu, uefi

Shall I reinstall everything, I'm a bit desperate to get back to mac os, I had backed up everything already?

**Edit** `System Bootorder not found, initializing defaults`

Everytime I restart I see this message on the black screen and then it boots into linux, I saw the same message when I didn't remove installation disk.

Restarting with option button pressed only gives EFIBoot option (no MacOS)

**Note**: I can get rid of Ubuntu from disk utility, if this can help?

---

First I followed these instructions to create a bootable disk and booted into ubuntu.
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview

I did have a hiccup when it asked me to remove the USB stick at the end of installation and it ran into some error but I restarted and it resumed the installation progress (not sure if this caused the error).

I'm restarting my Mac with option button pressed down but it always boots into Ubuntu.

Here's some output for `sudo efibootmgr -v`

```
BootCurrent: 0000 
BootOrder: 0000,0080 
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,af055076-a331-4c17-81b6-4ff1821c0dfa,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi) 
Boot0080* Mac OS X  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,1ad5b9b1-f157-4c78-bdf0-bc324e13f7f5,0x64028,0x3a373058)/VenMedia(be74fcf7-0b7c-49f3-9147-01f4042e6842,9f8e26c15883dc438b6e94376be95a4a)/File(\8DE7B754-E5BD-4846-A9C9-483D1DDDCE79\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi) 
BootFFFF*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,1ad5b9b1-f157-4c78-bdf0-bc324e13f7f5,0x64028,0x3a373058)/VenMedia(be74fcf7-0b7c-49f3-9147-01f4042e6842,9f8e26c15883dc438b6e94376be95a4a)/File(\4539D142-A5EA-4E7B-971B-A37558EDCD6D\com.apple.installer\boot.efi)
```

and for `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: hybrid
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 977105060 sectors, 465.9 GiB
Model: APPLE SSD SM0512
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 904406C5-D4C8-40B3-A21B-EC9ED9B1335C
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 977105026
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2145 sectors (1.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2         1050624       977104895   465.4 GiB   8300
```

Screenshots

[image]
[image]